# why allowing established incoming connections doesn't work?

Tags: iptables, conntrack

I am trying to allowing all established incoming connections in my iptables using this command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

but I get this error message:

```
"iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): Couldn't load match `conntrack':No such file or directory"
```

even that I do have conntrack install in my environment.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: What's the system you use? Show `uname -a`.

Comment: Linux 500F85DA 4.19.56-linux4sam-6.1 #1 Thu Aug 4 11:41:46 UTC 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: Which means, whoever built this system didn't include this module into the configuration. Look for instructions how to build a kernel yourself. Moreover, you're running quite old kernel, Linux4SAM already support recent 5.15 tree. Finally, are you sure this is business environment? Likely your question is better fit for unix&linux staskexchange.

Comment: This is not your case, but this error can also appear if you run without `sudo`.